# Microsoft Flow Record Form responses in SharePoint Yes/No

Tags: list, flow, yes-no-field, microsoft-forms

This is my first time on Stack Exchange, and I haven't found the answer to my question in the forum.

I have built a Microsoft Form in order to get some data recorded into a SharePoint list using Flow. I would like to fill a SharePoint item with the format type Yes/No.

In Flow, I cannot even select a field from the Form I made (I setup some other SharePoint items and it worked like a charm).

Can you please let me know how to format the question in Form, and how to setup my Flow?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Forms to collect the data fro users? or you are talking about any other form?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Forms.

Comment: ok. You check [this](https://www.knowledgewave.com/blog/connect-a-form-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-flow)? this is explained in this blog.

Comment: I checked it Ganesh, thank you. The user has some Yes/No questions in his form, however I believe he set up the sharepoint items as Choice type (with choices being Yes or No), rather than using the type Yes/No. This is a workaround, yet it is not exactly what I am hoping for.

Comment: Then you might need to use dynamic expressions. If your choice on form is Yes then set boolean true to your SharePoint field else set false.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your SharePoint Yes/No type of field to Boolean true/false based on your selection in Microsoft form. You might need to use expression to Enter custom value in Yes/No field.

You can try one of the following expression and see what works best for you:

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['FormFieldName'], true)

@equals(triggerBody()?['FormFieldName'], bool(1))

@equals(triggerBody()?['FormFieldName'], bool(Yes))

@equals(triggerBody()?['FormFieldName'], bool(True))
```

Comment: Ganesh, I didn't quite manage to run this yet, but I am going to make some research on how to use dynamic expressions. I thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, your are supportive, thanks! I am getting more skilled in Flow, I shall make another attempt next week.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.